# English translation as drupal message

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am trying to add the English title as a drupal_set_message on all node pages if available - (Ive done something similar on the CMS) and if the user has node edit permissions (this can be checked using the node_access function).

Code for cms example mentioned. Inside a hook form alter.

```
// Translation display on CMS page
$nid = (isset($form['nid']['#value'])) ? $form['nid']['#value'] : false;
if($nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);

    if($node) {
        $lang = 'en';
        $translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);

        $translated_node = (isset($translations[$lang])) ? node_load($translations[$lang]->nid) : $node;
        $translated_title = '<h3>English Translation: ' . $translated_node->title . '</h3>';
    }
}

$form['#prefix'] = (isset($translated_title) && $translated_node->title != $node->title) ? $translated_title : '';
```

I am now wanting something similar but as a drupal_set_message on all node pages.

Comment: You could write almost the same in a hook_node_view() i suppose, and use drupal_set_message() in there.

Comment: Set messages had a weird response, like it was a page behind. The correct title only showed up on reload or redirect. 

Solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by using the following code in the template file.

```php
$node = menu_get_object();

if (node_access('update', $node)):
    $lang = 'en';
    $translations = translation_node_get_translations($node->tnid);
    $translated_node = (isset($translations[$lang])) ? node_load($translations[$lang]->nid) : $node;
    if(is_object($translated_node)):
?>
  <div class="title-container">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>English title: <b><?php print $translated_node->title; ?></b></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ok, this is a solution but surely not a god one.i think you misunderstand the drupal_set_message(). Since you are doing this in your theme, at least you could write this in a preprocess_HOOK (u dont need node_load in there)...